# Why PowerShell lists first entry of imported CSV as variable name?

Tags: powershell

I want to print a list of users after importing from a CSV

I have run my `$users` variable from the terminal, tried calling the variable as an array and tried to `Write-Host` from a loop going through the list of users.

```
$users = @(Import-CSV .\users.csv)

foreach ($user in $users) {
write-host $user }
```

I am expecting all the users to be displayed like the list in CSV:

```
Jack null
Ally Staniforth
John Hill
Samantha Sullivan
Danny Allen
```

Albeit the actual output is:

```
@{Jodie Stockham=Jason Dickson}
@{Jodie Stockham=Dwayne Bartlett-Kennedy}
@{Jodie Stockham=Mark Lamprey}
@{Jodie Stockham=Anthony Triggs}
@{Jodie Stockham=Allan Hood}
```

Comment: Please remember to always copy your code from the editor, not from the console (as in that case it used to have unnecessary `>> ` before `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your file contains header? From the output it looks like it's just a list of names:

```
Jodie Stockham
Jason Dickson
Dwayne Bartlett-Kennedy
Mark Lamprey
Anthony Triggs
Allan Hood
```

In that case you don't need to use `Import-CSV` (which consider first line as headers), but you can simply use `Get-Content`:

```bsh
$users = Get-Content .\users.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
    Write-Host $user
}
```

If you only want to list the names, you don't have to use `foreach` at all, just use the variable directly:

```bsh
PS> $users
Jodie Stockham
Jason Dickson
Dwayne Bartlett-Kennedy
Mark Lamprey
Anthony Triggs
Allan Hood
```

**NOTE**: you can easily check what I mentioned above using that cmdlet:

```bsh
PS> Import-CSV .\users.csv
```

Output will be like this (first name as a header):

```bsh
Jodie Stockham
--------------
Jason Dickson
Dwayne Bartlett-Kennedy
Mark Lamprey
Anthony Triggs
Allan Hood
```